# Initializing APIResource instance, causes scope error - why?

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-core, openid, identityserver4

Initializing APIResource instance in Code 1 should be equivalent to Code 2

Code1 (refer to line 24 to 30 from identityserver4 quick start  repo) https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Config.cs#L24-L30

```
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
           new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
        };
    }
```

Code2

```
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {

            new ApiResource
            {
                Name = "api1",
                DisplayName = "My API"
            }

        };
    }
```

However, identityserver4 indicates there is an error with scope in code2 (**Sorry, there was an error : invalid_scope**)

why?

Comment: The constructor also adds the displayname to the scope propery, which seems to be required for some reasone. The empty constructor should propably be private or internal to avoid confusions like this.